# Proof regarding quasi-solutions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm almost done proving a theorem regarding quasi-solutions, which I'm stating here:

$Let\ A:X\rightarrow Y\ be\ a\ compact\ linear\ operator\ and\ let\ \rho>0.\ Then\ for\ each\ f\in Y\ there\ exists\ a\ unique\ element\ \varphi_0\in X\ with\ ||\varphi_0||\leq\rho\ satisfying$

$$||A\varphi_0-f||\leq||A\varphi-f||$$

$for\ all\ \varphi\in X\ with\ ||\varphi||\leq\rho.$

Here $X$ and $Y$ are Hilbert spaces. The part of the proof I'm struggling with is the following (uniqueness): We're considering the set $V:=\{A\varphi\ |\ ||\varphi||\leq\rho\}$ since for $\varphi_0$ to be a quasi-solution with the constraint $\rho$, then it has to be the best approximation to the set $V$.

I've already shown that $V$ is a convex set. The problem now is to show that there in the Hilbert space $Y$ exist at most one best approximation to $f$ with respect to the set $V$.

Here's my idea on how to do it (showing uniqueness of the quasi-solution):

If we consider two points $v_0,v_1\in V$ in which we assume they both are the best approximation to some element $y\in Y$, i.e., $||y-v_0||=||y-v_1||$. Now, we should consider the line segment between $v_0$ and $v_1$ (we know this is contained in $V$ since it is convex) and consider the distance from that to $y$, i.e., $||y-(tv_0+(1-t)v_1)||$ for $t\in[0,1]$. My idea is now to show that one can find a unique $t$ for which the distance is the smallest. This will contradict the assumption that both $v_0$ and $v_1$ were the best approximations to $y$ since we've now found a new one.

Does this seem correct or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should state at the beginning, what spaces $X$ (and $Y$) are (probably Hilbert spaces). Then it is unclear whether your question is also about existence of $\varphi_0$ or if you are only interested in uniqueness.

Comment: Sorry, both $X$ and $Y$ are Hilbert spaces. I have shown existence of the quasi-solution so I'm only interested in uniqueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea to consider the line between $v_1,v_0$ is a good start.
However, it is often enough to only consider the central point $v_2:=\tfrac12(v_0+v_1)$ to get a contradiction.

Here is a sketch on how to do this:

Using the parallelogram law, we have
$$
 2\|y-v_0\|^2+2\|y-v_1\|^2 = \|2y-v_0-v_1\|^2+\|v_0-v_1\|^2
 =4\|y-v_2\|^2+\|v_0-v_1\|^2.
$$
Now if you assume that $v_0\neq v_1$ then it follows that $v_2$ is a better solution than $v_1$ or $v_0$.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I've tried it myself and I got the same as you with the parallelogram law. This is just to see if I understand why you can argue $v_2$ is a better choice than $v_0$ or $v_1$:

We assumed that $||y-v_0||=||y-v_1||$ and $v_0\neq v_1$, which means by the parallelogram law we have

$$4||y-v_0||^2=4||y-v_2||^2+||v_0-v_1||$$

which means that $v_2$ is a better approximation, due to $||v_0-v_1||^2$ term, right?

Comment: Or one could write the LHS of the parallelogram law with $v_1$, but the idea is that it shows that 4 times the distance between $y$ and $v_0$ or $v_1$ yields 4 times the distance of $y$ and $v_2$ plus an additional distance, namely the distance between $v_0$ and $v_1$, which means $v_2$ must approximate $y$ better.

Comment: yes, that is correct